# Configuring css-loader with publicPath

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader

I have a .scss file with a class:

```
.my-class {
  background-image: url("/images/image.svg")
}
```

When building with webpack i'm using a publicPath in my configuration. Let's say my public path is `XYZ`

i'd like to find a way to find the generated css to look like:

```
.my-class {
  background-image: url("/XYZ/images/image.svg")
}
```

All the other assets generated seem to honor that publicPath variable so it's unclear what i've misconfigured. My config looks like this:

```
 {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: require.resolve('style-loader') },
          {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              camelCase: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve('sass-loader')
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: This worked for me automatically before upgrading to webpack 5 and css-loader@5.0.1. This worked for me previoously with css-loader@3.4.2

Answer (score 1):

So the easiest thing I've seen to fix this is to update your css-loader options to `url: false`.

This previously worked out of the box for me with css-loader@3.4.2 but looks like you now need this option.

My webpack now looks like this:

```
...
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
              },
              url: false, //<------------ this guy helped
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      ...
    ],
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inject a `scss` variable that holds `publicPath` value using webpack.

Pass the `scss variable with your value` under the `options` in `sass-loader`

```
var publicpath = "/static/images";
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options :{
                    data:"$publicpath : "+publicpath+";$red : red;$blue:blue;"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

in `main.scss` or any `.scss` you can access the value

```
.h1{
    color: $red;
}
.h2{
    color: $blue;
}
.img{
    background-image: url($publicpath+"/pic.jpg");
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this seems like it will work but it seems weird to be injecting this since it seems like something webpack would handle automatically. Maybe i'm wrong in assuming this is in the scope of css-loader?

Comment: @john_ryan  in the answer you can see the sass variable going under the options of `sass-loader`. `sass-loader` has provided this option specifically for this kind of requirement

Comment: @john_ryan what i've mentioned is a way to inject your public path into sass. public path for your assets should be configured like this.  https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#root

Comment: @diving I gave this a shot, but it causes a different issue `Can't resolve './XYZ/pic.svg`, not sure if this is coming from `css-loader` or `sass-loader`

Comment: @john_ryan what kind of shot you give? Share your code via git or something

Comment: I was able to get it working if i set `url: false` in `css-loader`, OR i put a / in front of my $publicpath otherwise `css-loader` looks for the file on disk.